# Javascript module loaders and critical rendering path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, commonjs, jspm

What i understand is, when you use module loaders, your scripts ( modules ) are loaded asynchronously.

The question is If you are manipulating dom, how does the browser / module loader figures out to execute such scripts correctly? How does it knows what sequecne i need to execute these modules into ? Specially when you are using angularjs with jspm  / common.js or any other module loader

Answer (score 0):

Any loader doesn't know anything about DOM, node states and so on, at most it has binding for `window`'s `load` event. Francly speaking, they works like this:

- First such loaders loads itself,
- after it they loads some root module
  (called `entry point`),
- after it looks for a root script dependencies
  and load them,
- for each dependency it checks dependecy's dependencies and so on,
- after all dependencied loaded it begins to inject latter dependencies into previous,
- after injecting dependencies to the root module it calling it.

[image: Executing order]